# RazorEngine IsolatedTemplateService is not preventing growth of number of loaded assemblies

Tags: appdomain, razorengine

I am attempting to use the `IsolatedTemplateService` in RazorEngine 3.2.0.

According to http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=473, this should prevent an ever-increasing number of assemblies from being loaded into my main AppDomain.

This doesn't seem to be the case, however.  I am using PerfMon to monitor the number of loaded assemblies and each time I execute a template, the counter value goes up.

### Repro:

1) Open perfmon and start watching the **.NET CLR Loading: Current Assemblies** and **.NET CLR Loading: Current Appdomains** counters

2) Parse a template using the IsolatedTemplateService

### Results:

The "Current Appdomains" counter DOES spike up when the template is parsed, and then drops back down afterwards. It does look like a separate appdomain is being created.

The "Current Assemblies" counter just keeps going up. It does NOT drop back down at any time.

Am I reading these counters wrong? Or is the IsolatedTemplateService failing to constrain the dynamic assembly creation to the temporary AppDomain?